Azure DevOps: passing runtime parameters for copy task (using conditional insert) - template expression
I'm defining these parameters in Azure_pipeline.yaml:
parameters:
- name: 'buildtype'
  default: entire
  type: string
  values:
  - entire
  - reduced

I've defined this copy task in task.yaml using the few other stages & jobs templates and parameters values:
steps:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.buildtype, 'entire') }}:
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: Deploy ${{ parameters.buildtype }} Build to ${{ parameters.deploymentFolder }}
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ parameters.appName }}
      Contents: |
                **
                !.config/**/*
      TargetFolder: ${{ parameters.deploymentFolder }}
      OverWrite: true
      flattenFolders: false
      enabled: true 
    
- ${{ if eq(parameters.buildtype, 'reduced') }}:
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    displayName: Deploy ${{ parameters.buildtype }} Build to ${{ parameters.deploymentFolder }}
    inputs:
      SourceFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ parameters.appName }}
      Contents: |
                **
                !.config/**/*
                !$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ parameters.appName }}/appsettings.Staging
      TargetFolder: ${{ parameters.deploymentFolder }}
      OverWrite: true
      flattenFolders: false
      enabled: true

From this task, I am trying to copy the required files to deployment folder, based on the Run time parameter values=entire/reduced name=buildtype. During the pipeline run, it's evaluating as "False".
I haven't shared the complete template and values due to restrictions.
Ref: Conditional insertion - Microsoft docs

What exactly is being evaluated as False? Does the right CopyFiles@2 task run depending on the selected value of buildtype parameter?

@RuiJarimba Copy task evaulting as false and execution skipped from the pipeline run

You must be invoking the task.yaml with an invalid value. I suggest you add a dummy task to the beginning of the template that just prints the value of parameters.buildtype

It would help to see how you're invoking task.yaml and the list of parameters of that template.

@RuiJarimba I need to copy the files based on my Runtime parameters, is the condition(if) I am using in task.yaml will satisfy my requirement??

What I'm trying to say is that if none of the CopyFiles@2 tasks are generated it means that parameter.buildtype is not entire nor reduced. As I already suggested, add a dummy task to the beginning of the template that just prints the value of parameters.buildtype to confirm if you're using the right values or not.

@RuiJarimba test script prints null value for parameters

It would help to see how you're invoking task.yaml and the list of parameters of that template. Without that, we can only make assumptions about what wrong.

Hi @rtqr, welcome to stack overflow. I tested the answer shared by @Rui Jarimba. The value of parameters.buildtype is correct and it will copy the files based on the Runtime parameter parameters.buildtype. The problem is that we didn't know how you use the template in your pipeline. Please check this guidance How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example and share some more details to reproduce the issue.

@MiaoTian-MSFT  Azure_pipeline.yaml
In this pipeline

parameters
trigger
pool details
stages --> Inside will call template with Stages and Jobs(Build and Deploy)
Build - will call build template with defined tasks related to .net build
Deploy- will call deploy template with multiple Steps,tasks( copy task)

Above is the hierarchy of pipeline and templates usage

Here i am defining the RUN time parameter values for buildtype in Azure_pipeline.yaml
and Calling the parameters with if condition in copytask(task.yaml ).


@MiaoTian-MSFT   Azure_pipeline.yaml
I have tried Rui Jarimba solution with parameters and condition but cmd line script task  for test ( echo== output no values)
Entire project is template based ( CICD )

Hi @rtqr, do you mean in this script task echo "Deploying ${{ parameters.buildtype }} Build", the ${{ parameters.buildtype }} is empty in the output? If it is, the value is not passed to the template. You can double check the difference between your yaml and the yaml shared in the answer, or the yaml sample in the document.

It would be better if you can edit your question to share a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

@rtqr - Can you share - how are you including this template 'Azure_pipeline.yaml', how are you passing the parameter 'buildtype', I guess that may not be right...

Hi Guys,
Now the runtime parameters are consuming successfully by task.yaml, issue with parameters passing in parent pipeline I am not explicitly passing the values for parameters in parent_pipeline.yaml till now passing only in Azure_pipeline.yaml now it's working fine with below values

name: buildtype
type: string
default: entire


Thank you @RuiJarimba  - For sharing the reference
Miao Tian-MSFT

You're referencing parameters buildtype, appName and deploymentFolder in your template (tasks.yaml) but you forgot to define them.
Try the following:
# task.yaml

parameters:
  - name: 'buildtype'
    displayName: 'Build Type'
    type: string

  - name: 'appName'
    displayName: 'Application Name'
    type: string

  - name: 'deploymentFolder'
    displayName: 'Deployment Folder'
    type: string

steps:
  - script: |
      echo "Deploying ${{ parameters.buildtype }} Build"
    displayName: 'Deploy ${{ parameters.buildtype }} Build'

  - ${{ if eq(parameters.buildtype, 'entire') }}:
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: Deploy ${{ parameters.buildtype }} Build to ${{ parameters.deploymentFolder }}
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ parameters.appName }}
        Contents: |
          **
          !.config/**/*
        TargetFolder: ${{ parameters.deploymentFolder }}
        OverWrite: true
        flattenFolders: false
        enabled: true 
      
  - ${{ if eq(parameters.buildtype, 'reduced') }}:
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: Deploy ${{ parameters.buildtype }} Build to ${{ parameters.deploymentFolder }}
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ parameters.appName }}
        Contents: |
          **
          !.config/**/*
          !$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/${{ parameters.appName }}/appsettings.Staging
        TargetFolder: ${{ parameters.deploymentFolder }}
        OverWrite: true
        flattenFolders: false
        enabled: true

Using the template - example:
# Azure_pipeline.yaml

parameters:
  - name: 'buildtype'
    displayName: 'Build Type'
    type: string
    default: entire
    values:
    - entire
    - reduced

trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
  # other tasks here

  - template: task.yaml
    parameters:
      buildtype: ${{ parameters.buildtype }}
      appName: 'myapp'
      deploymentFolder: '/my/deployment/folder'


as per your suggestion, updated the parameters and using in Azure pipelines and task.yaml no luck, values are not storing in parameter during the copy task {{ parameters.buildtype }} not referring to the values defined

@rtqr you still haven't shown all the required information to help solve your issue - for example, how are you using the template? I understand that you cannot show the whole code, but you must share enough in order to reproduce the issue.
